# how change color line in DatePicker JavaFx

Tags: java, css, javafx, datepicker

How change black color line in Date-Picker to white color?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4FwL.jpg)

Comment: Where is code? 

or you can change in css border color like {border:1px solid #000;} accordingly.

Comment: This Date-Picker is from JFoenix librarian.

Comment: is their any demo on fiddle?

Comment: .date-picker-popup .calendar-grid {
    -fx-pref-width: 220.0;
    -fx-pref-height: 100.0;
}
.date-picker-popup .spinner-label {
    -fx-font-size: 12.0;
    
}

Comment: this is my code for datepicker where add "border:1px solid #000" ? I can new class .date-picker-popup{ } ?

Comment: @hlalu12 You should update your question with that css, as not everyone always reads the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It appears to have focused line color too.

```
.jfx-date-picker .input-line {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.jfx-date-picker .input-focused-line {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

[Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) might helps you to analyze runtime scene graph.

[image]